# "CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22" and "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock"

Tags: linux, share, mount, cifs, superblock

I've been using a linux server for quite some time now with mounts to several windows shares by using the cifs mounts.

so far I always had a line in /etc/fstab:
//IPADDRESS/sharename /mnt/localfolder cifs soft,username=xxx,password=xxx,_netdev,uid=500,gid=501 0 0

Since my last reboot (probably applying new kernel updates) I'm unable to mount my shares.

Current kernel: 3.4.76-65.111.amzn1.x86_64

This is what I checked and the results of the commands:

**1. Network environment did not change, and shares/ip's are reachable and usable from other PC's.**

**2. cifs-utils, nfs4-acl-tools, nfs-utils are installed and portmap is running**

**3. manual mount command (that always worked):**

mount -t cifs -o credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,_netdev,uid=500,gid=501 //IPADDRESS/sharename /mnt/localmap/

RETURNS:
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //IPADDRESS/sharename,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount. helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

**4. dmesg | tail returns:**

CIFS VFS: Connecting to DFS root not implemented yet
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22

Any ideas what else I could try or what this could be?

Comment: Is the cifs module loaded? `modprobe cifs`

Comment: yes, but I managed to fix the problem a bit differently as you can see in the update of my post above .

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER MOVED FROM QUESTION**

I needed to install the samba3-cifsmount. I did the following:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/

wget http://ftp.sernet.de/pub/samba/3.5/centos/6/sernet-samba.repo

yum update

yum install samba3-cifsmount
```

In case you get a message like "no mirrors available" you can also directly download the rpm from the producer's site: http://ftp.sernet.de/pub/samba/3.5/centos/6/x86_64/

for manual install type:

```
rpm -Uvh downloadedfile.rpm
```